undefined reference to llvm.x86.rdrand.16.sl_s intrinsic
I have an LLVM pass inserting a call to the RDRAND intrinsic (using irBuilder.CreateIntrinsic(Intrinsic::x86_rdrand_16, {ReturnType}, {})). I'm able to successfully generate this IR:
%1 = alloca i32, align 4
%2 = call { i16, i32 } @llvm.x86.rdrand.16.sl_s()
%3 = extractvalue { i16, i32 } %2, 0
%4 = and i16 %3, 1
%bar= alloca i32, i16 %4, align 4
%5 = alloca i32, align 4
%6 = alloca i32, align 4
store i32 0, ptr %1, align 4
store i32 1, ptr %5, align 4
store i32 2, ptr %6, align 4
%7 = load ptr, ptr @stdout, align 8
%8 = load i32, ptr %5, align 4
%9 = load i32, ptr %6, align 4
%10 = add nsw i32 %8, %9
%11 = call i32 (ptr, ptr, ...) @fprintf(ptr noundef %7, ptr noundef @.str, ... i32 noundef %10)
ret i32 0

I then try to generate an executable using: clang -target $(gcc -dumpmachine) -mrdrnd foo.bc -o foo.o. This however gives me the error:
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /tmp/foo-714550.o: in function `main':
foo.c:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `llvm.x86.rdrand.16.sl_s'

How does one link the required LLVM libraries that provide these intrinsics?

If the intrinsic actually worked, there shouldn't be a function call in the generated object file, just the machine code for an rdrand instruction.  Your -mrdrnd should be letting the compiler inline it.
